# Granting access to SQL Server database from ASP.Net application

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, authentication

I've set up a login page for a .NET web application but when I try to log one of the users on my database in I get this error.

> *Cannot open database "SampleLaundrySystem" requested by the login. The login failed.
>   Login failed for user*

After doing some research I found I ran this query in an attempt to give myself access to the server

```
EXEC sp_grantlogin 'MyMachineName\ASPNET' /* Give the ASPNET account access to DB*/ 
EXEC sp_grantdbaccess 'MyMachineName\ASPNET' /* Give the ASPNET account full privileges to DB*/ 
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_owner', 'MyMachineName\ASPNET'
```

The above still didn't work and I'm getting an error saying the 'MyMachineName' was not found.

I need help on how to get this sorted or pointers to what I'm doing wrong. Please find below my connection string:

```
<add name="SampleName" 
     connectionString="Server=localhost\SqlExpress;Database=SampleLaundrySystem;Integrated Security=True"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Thanks in advance for everything.

Comment: Try dropping the 'MyMachineName\' in front of the username

Comment: What kind of authentication do you have set up for your ASP.NET application?

Comment: I'm using Windows authentication for the application. @SteveMayne I don't understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

change integrated security =SSPI

follow this link: http://www.connectionstrings.com/

Comment: Changed integrated security to SSPI but still got the same outcome the connection strings dont seem to change much either.

Comment: is the database file on your local?

Comment: Hi everyone, I solved the problem by creating the database in sql management studio where I have the relevant access rights and changing the data source and connection string of my application to the new one(ie sql management studio database). Works just fine now :)